# The prerequisites for a change of variables in a double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given a double integral, I want to find out what should I prove for the equality:
$$
\int \int _\Omega f(x,y) dx dy = \int \int _{\Omega_{new}} f(x(u,v),y(u,v))\cdot J dudv
$$

My dilemma is as follows:
I know that the condition $J\neq 0$ in the domain $\Omega$ implies the validity of the inverse function theorem , and in particular that my mapping $u=u(x,y), v=v(x,y)$ is injective. But, if so, why does all the statements that I find of the theorem of changing variables has the two conditions: $ J\neq 0 $ **and** our mapping in injective ?

In addition, why does for linear mappings $u,v$ it is enough to check the Jacobian does not vanish ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition $J\ne 0$ only ensures *local* invertibility of the map (the inverse function theorem is all about "neighborhoods", isn't it?). For example, the map given in polar coordinates by $(r,\theta)\to(r,2\theta)$ has nonzero Jacobian in the region $1<r<2$, but it's not invertible, being 2-to-1.

For linear maps, there's a linear algebra theorem saying that a matrix with nonzero determinant has an inverse. That works globally.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  I completely understand this, but , as you said - since $J\neq 0 $ ensures local invertibility , why can't we just partition our domain of integration into separate neighberhoods , such that in each neighberhood the inverse function theorem applies ? Hope I made my self clear now. Thanks a lot !

Comment: You can have, say, neighborhoods $A$ and $B $ such that $f$ is injective in $A$ and is injective in $B$. But if $f(A)$ overlaps $f(B)$, you are double-counting things.

Comment: so can't I then ommit $f(A) \cap f(B)$  ?

Comment: Think of what you just wrote and what it means in the context of integrals. (Hint: nothing)

Comment: Got it ! Thanks !!!!